# Does Microsoft Sync framework supports this scenario?(synchronization by file's)

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have completely offline two Ms sql server's. I need to synchronize them by file exchanging. This is only possible way. In other words synchronization conversation of framework to turn into the files??

Comment: Hi, please go more in detail. You want only update the other ms sql server or you want to merge the data?

Comment: I want to make synchronization between two servers via file's. Transport would be train, plane, by post office etc :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can send the changes via files, the answer is no.

The best workaround you have is to sync to a SQL CE database, and then send and sync the SQL CE database back and forth between the databases.